# Sunspot and HABTM relationship with two search fields in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, solr, model-associations, sunspot-rails

I have an ActiveRecord model **(Profile)** that has a **HABTM** association to model **(Subject)**.
I am using Sunspot to search for all **Profiles** based on **two fields** that will be entered by user which is **:zip** and **(subject.title)**.

I tried so many different examples on stackoverflow and exhausted my attempts at trying to find the answer.  I am definitely new to rails and I would appreciate any help with this.  Thank you.

**Profile model**

```
class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base

has_and_belongs_to_many :subjects 

  searchable do
  string :zip
  string :title do
  subjects.title
  end

end
```

**ProfilesController#Index**

```
def index
 @search = Profile.search do
   with(:zip, params[:zip])
   # Don't know what to put here if this is even correct... ???
  end
  @profiles = @search.results
end
```

**ProfilesView#Index**

```
    <%= form_tag profiles_path, method: :get do %>
<p>
    <p>Enter Zip:</p>
    <%= text_field_tag :zip, params[:search] %>

    <p>Enter Subject:</p>
    <%= text_field_tag :title, params[:search] %>

    <%= submit_tag "Search", name: nil %>
</p>
<% end %>

    <% for profile in @profiles %>
    <ul style="list-style:none;">
        <li> <%= link_to profile.name, profile %> </li>
        <li> <%= profile.zip %></li>
        <li><b>($<%= profile.rate %>)</b></li>
         <% profile.subjects.each do |s| %> 
         <li> <%= s.title %> </li>
         <% end %>
    </ul>
    <% end %>
```

Answer (score 1):

Found out how to do it...

**Profile Model**

```
class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_and_belongs_to_many :subjects 

  searchable do
  text :subject_search
  string :zip
  end

  def subject_search
    subjects.map { |subject| subject.title }
  end

end
```

**Profiles#Controller**

```
 def index
   @search = Profile.search do
    fulltext :params[:subject_search]
    with(:zip, params[:zip])
    end
   @profiles = @search.results
end
```

**Profiles#Index**

```
    <%= form_tag profiles_path, method: :get do %>
 <p>
    <p>Enter Zip:</p>
    <%= text_field_tag :zip, params[:search] %>

    <p>Enter Subject:</p>
    <%= text_field_tag :subject_search, params[:search] %>

    <%= submit_tag "Search", name: nil %>
</p>
<% end %>
```